# Changing background row color in reportviewer based on date

Tags: c#, reporting-services

There are multiple answers on how to change the background color of a row in a report viewer based on a column value. I actually used one like so:

```
=Iif(Fields!Age.Value <= 15, "LimeGreen", 
Iif(Fields!Age.Value <= 30, "Blue", 
Iif(Fields!Age.Value <=45, "Yellow", 
Iif(Fields!Age.Value <=60, "Brown", "Red"))))
```

But what I want right now is to change the background color to light blue as soon as a date is greater than November 30, 2015
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using Switch statement:

```
=Switch(
Fields!Date.Value > CDATE("2015-11-30"),"Light Blue",
Fields!Age.Value <= 15, "LimeGreen",
Fields!Age.Value <= 30, "Blue",
Fields!Age.Value <= 45, "Yellow",
Fields!Age.Value <= 60, "Brown",
true, "Red"
)
```

Let me know if this helps you.